# Using session values in the body of an email

Tags: vb.net

I created the body of an email by using the following bit of code:

```
 msgBody &= " Name: " & Venuename & vbNewLine  & "Address:" & _
         "" & Venueaddress & nxtline & "City: " & Venuecity & nxtline & "State:" & _
         "" &  Venuestate & nxtline & "Zip: " & Venuezip & nxtline & "Phone: " & Venuephone & nxtline & "Type: " & _
         "" & Venuetype & nxtline & "Date of expected use: " & Convert.ToDateTime(Venuedate) & HttpContext.Current.Session["UFName"].ToString() &  & _
         "" & HttpContext.Current.Session["ULFName"].ToString() & HttpContext.Current.Session["Territory"].ToString()
```

Is this the proper way to do so? How can I improve my code?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The reason you are currently being downvoted is because the code you are showing is only a small part of your code, which removes a bunch of context. Unlike Stack Overflow, we prefer to look at real code instead of example code.

Answer (score 5):

String concatenation like that results in code that is not maintainable and looks ugly. You have other options to achieve the same:

**String.Format:**

Use the [**`String.Format()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) method to concatenate values, a small example:

```
Dim name As String = "Bill"
Dim city As String = "New York
Dim message As String = String.Format("Name: {0}{1} City: {2}", name, vbNewLine, city)
```

As you see, you can also add other variables like the `vbNewLine` although in .NET I suggest you use `Environment.Newline` instead.

**StringBuilder:**

Perhaps, using the [**`StringBuilder`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class is even better since you're creating a long string. And then even the String.Format can look messy. Here's another short example:

```
Dim stringBuilder As New StringBuilder()

stringBuilder.Append("Name: ")
stringBuilder.AppendLine(name)
stringBuilder.Append("City: ")
stringBuilder.AppendLine(city)

msgBody = stringBuilder.ToString()
```

You can also use `AppendFormat()` instead of `Append`:

```
stringBuilder.AppendFormat("Name: {0}", name)
stringBuilder.AppendLine()
stringBuilder.AppendFormat("City: {1}", city)
stringBuilder.AppendLine()
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this would be a much more readable way to do it:

```
    Dim Message As String = <html>
                                <body>
                                    <p>Your Name: {NAME}</p>
                                    <p>Address: {ADDRESS}</p>
                                    <p>State: {CITY}</p>
                                </body>
                            </html>.ToString

    Dim MergeFields As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    With MergeFields
        .Add("{NAME}", HttpContext.Current.Session("Name"))
        .Add("{ADDRESS}", "123, My Street...")
        .Add("{CITY}", HttpContext.Current.Session("City"))
    End With

    For Each f In MergeFields
        Message = Message.Replace(f.Key, f.Value)
    Next
```

Note: Don't forget to call "ToString" at the end of the message content. Otherwise "Message" would be an XElement. Don't have to do that if your message content is just text instead of HTML like above.